# How do I implement glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT) in OpenGL ES 1.x

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I'm trying to modify my OpenGL project to OpenGL ES 1.x. But there is a function call I can't find any solution for me to replace it.

```
glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL_LIGHTING_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT );
```

I can't find GL_CURRENT_BIT mask and glPushAttrib function in OpenGL ES 1.x.

Simply, I just remove the GL_CURRENT_BIT mask from the glPushAttrib parameters, and the application show the wrong background on the window(I tested it on the OpenGL environment. and the background is a texutre.). Is there any solution for me to replace glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT) and let me run the application correctly on the OpenGL or Is there any solution for me to implement glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT) which I can run both on OpenGL and OpenGL ES correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`glPushAttrib`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml) does not exist in OpenGL ES. The function that is intended to take the `GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT` as an input is actually [`glPushClientAttrib`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushClientAttrib.xml), which also doesn't exist (and thus, neither does the constant).

The functionality of these is essentially to store all states that can be set with the [`glPixelStorei`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glPixelStorei.xml) function. This can be implemented manually, by recording these states as they are set, and making the equivalent calls to `glPixelStorei` to restore them. See [here](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/) (item #8) for a discussion (which about OpenGL, by applies to OpenGL ES, in that, it doesn't have `glPush/PopClientAttrib`).

Comment: thanks for your answering. I'm sorry, I write a wrong constant. Which I'm really want to ask is GL_CURRENT_BIT.  Is there any solution for me to replace glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT)?

Comment: The same solution applies to your modified question, except with different states. If you go to the link for `glPushAttrib`, there is a table indicating what states it saves. In GLES, you will just have to record these settings (in your code) and set them again to get the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem. I find an open source project named glues. It implements the glPushAttrib function. thanks again.